# Error reading font file when using Icepdf

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, icepdf

I am writing a program where I need to display PDFs inside a JPanel. To do so I am using the ICEPDF library.
The problem is that with some PDFs I got the following exception:

```
WARNING: Error reading font file with
java.io.IOException: 'head' table is mandatory
    at org.apache.fontbox@2.0.27/org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parseTables(TTFParser.java:198)
    at org.apache.fontbox@2.0.27/org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:165)
    at org.apache.fontbox@2.0.27/org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:110)
    at icepdf.core@7.1.3/org.icepdf.core.pobjects.fonts.zfont.fontFiles.ZFontTrueType.<init>(ZFontTrueType.java:60)
```

The file opens anyway but it takes much longer than if exception doesn't occur (4 seconds versus 1 second).
Code for the displayPdf is:

```
void displayPdf(File selectedFile, JPanel homeContainer, CardLayout c1) {
        String filePath = selectedFile.getPath();
        SwingController controller = new SwingController();
        SwingViewBuilder factory = new SwingViewBuilder(controller);
        JPanel viewerComponentPanel = factory.buildViewerPanel();
        ComponentKeyBinding.install(controller, viewerComponentPanel);
        controller.getDocumentViewController().setAnnotationCallback(
                new org.icepdf.ri.common.MyAnnotationCallback(
                        controller.getDocumentViewController()));
        JFrame window = new JFrame("PDF file");
        window.getContentPane().add(viewerComponentPanel);
        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);
        controller.openDocument(filePath);
}
```

I think the problem is connected with the lack of fonts, but I do not know what to do.
I have set `org.icepdf.core.awtFontLoading` to `true` but this didn't fix the issue.

Thank you very much for any kind of help!

Comment: Looks more to me like the font file it found is corrupt

Comment: where the font file used by ICEPDF is located and how can i fix it? i don't have any experience working with fonts...thanks...

Comment: Fonts are normally embedded in PDF files - but not always. What is probably happening here is that these files do not have embedded fonts. The font library is trying to load a substitute font, but failing (the HEAD table is the first thing read when reading a TrueType font, you see). It's not a great error message but my guess is the substitute font is not corrupt - it just can't be found on disk. Look into how your PDF library finds substitute fonts.

Comment: thanks...there is an explanation about font substituion for ICEPDF on this link https://www.icesoft.org/wiki/display/PDF/Deploying+Fonts+with+an+Application#:~:text=When%20fonts%20are%20not%20embedded,1).. i wonder if i can use .ttf files instead of .pfb...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using 7.x so the most up-to-date docs can be found at https://github.com/pcorless/icepdf/wiki.  The system property org.icepdf.core.awtFontLoading is no longer applicable as the library is now using FontBox to render embedded fonts and ready system fonts.  The older < 7.x property was used when the Open source library could only read some embedded fonts with AWT.

When the file loads a font that isn't embedded or fails to load an embedded font it fall back to font substitution.  Font substitution will will kick off a processes to read all the available system fonts and try to find an appropriate font to render.  This processes is expensive if the cache isn't used.  This will enable the cache:

```
// read/store the font cache.
FontPropertiesManager.getInstance().loadOrReadSystemFonts();
```

I haven't looked into suppressing the warning as it is technically valid.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer…this way the loading is considerably faster and this is the solution to my problem…icing on the cake would be to set in the code the font to use (since the files to be displayed all use the same font)…when I have time I will work on it…

Comment: If you are able to share the file create an issue on github page above and attach it.  I can take closer look at what is going on.

Comment: Issue submitted https://github.com/pcorless/icepdf/issues/326